# Avoid manual naming of columns operated on multiple outputs from summarise_each (or dmap)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have probabilities predicted from model `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` (in reality, I have many more models). Within a give year, I have probabilities by area. I want to divide the (sum of my annual probabilities per area) by the (sum of my annual probabilities). No problem. However, for many columns of model outputs, I'd like to do this without having to manually specify the operation for each column of model outputs.

First create dummy data that include a column of years, areas, and 3 columns of model outputs. Within a given year and area, there can be many records.

```
 model2 <- data.frame(year = sort(c(rep(2003:2005, 3), 2003, 2004, 2005)), 
                      areas = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 4), 
                      x1 = round(rnorm(12), 1), 
                      x2 = round(rnorm(12), 1), 
                      x3 = round(rnorm(12), 1))

 >model2

    year areas   x1   x2   x3
 1  2003     A -0.4  0.5 -0.5
 2  2003     B -1.7 -0.7 -0.4
 3  2003     C  0.1 -0.5  0.5
 4  2003     A  0.4 -1.0 -0.3
 5  2004     B -0.8  1.6  0.3
 6  2004     C -0.3 -0.8 -0.5
 7  2004     A -3.8  0.2 -0.6
 8  2004     B  1.1  0.0  0.0
 9  2005     C -1.7  0.6 -1.7
 10 2005     A  1.4  2.0  0.1
 11 2005     B -0.4  0.7  1.4
 12 2005     C  0.9 -0.6 -0.8
```

Sum the probabilities for each model by year and area.

```
bystat <- model2 %>% group_by(areas, year) %>% summarize_each(funs(sum))

 > bystat

 Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
 Groups: areas [?]

   areas  year    x1    x2    x3
  (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
 1      A  2003   0.0  -0.5  -0.8
 2      A  2004  -3.8   0.2  -0.6
 3      A  2005   1.4   2.0   0.1
 4      B  2003  -1.7  -0.7  -0.4
 5      B  2004   0.3   1.6   0.3
 6      B  2005  -0.4   0.7   1.4
 7      C  2003   0.1  -0.5   0.5
 8      C  2004  -0.3  -0.8  -0.5
 9      C  2005  -0.8   0.0  -2.5
```

Sum the probabilities for each model by year

```
byyear <- model2 %>% group_by(year) %>% summarize_each(funs(sum), -areas)

 > byyear

 Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

    year    x1    x2    x3
    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
 1  2003  -1.6  -1.7  -0.7
 2  2004  -3.8   1.0  -0.8
 3  2005   0.2   2.7  -1.0
```

Combine the two datasets and divide the area-year sums by the annual sums (I'm sure at this point, people are laughing at me - Totally open to suggestions). I'll round here to make cleaner outputs

```
 > left_join(bystat, byyear, by = c("year" = "year")) %>% 
       mutate(x1 = round(x1.x / x1.y, 1), 
              x2 = round(x2.x / x2.y, 1), 
              x3 = round(x3.x / x3.y, 1))

 Source: local data frame [9 x 11]
 Groups: areas [3]

    areas  year  x1.x  x2.x  x3.x  x1.y  x2.y  x3.y    x1    x2    x3
   (fctr) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
 1      A  2003   0.0  -0.5  -0.8  -1.6  -1.7  -0.7   0.0   0.3   1.1
 2      A  2004  -3.8   0.2  -0.6  -3.8   1.0  -0.8   1.0   0.2   0.7
 3      A  2005   1.4   2.0   0.1   0.2   2.7  -1.0   7.0   0.7  -0.1
 4      B  2003  -1.7  -0.7  -0.4  -1.6  -1.7  -0.7   1.1   0.4   0.6
 5      B  2004   0.3   1.6   0.3  -3.8   1.0  -0.8  -0.1   1.6  -0.4
 6      B  2005  -0.4   0.7   1.4   0.2   2.7  -1.0  -2.0   0.3  -1.4
 7      C  2003   0.1  -0.5   0.5  -1.6  -1.7  -0.7  -0.1   0.3  -0.7
 8      C  2004  -0.3  -0.8  -0.5  -3.8   1.0  -0.8   0.1  -0.8   0.6
 9      C  2005  -0.8   0.0  -2.5   0.2   2.7  -1.0  -4.0   0.0   2.5
```

In my final output, I'm just interested in `x1`, `x2`, `x3` (don't care about the intermediate `x1.x`, `x1.y`, etc). However, I'd like to not have to manually write the `x1.x`/`x1.y` part because I have many models in my actual data. Is there are way to more effectively take the output from my `bystat` and divide it by my `byyear` columns without writing everything out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the intermediary data.frames; you can just calculate directly:

```
model2 %>% group_by(year, areas) %>%    # summarise will ungroup the last level
    summarise_all(sum) %>%    # now just grouped by year
    # for every variable but areas, divide the value by the grouped sum and round
    mutate_at(vars(-areas), funs(round(. / sum(.), 1)))

## Source: local data frame [9 x 5]
## Groups: year [3]
## 
##    year  areas    x1    x2    x3
##   <int> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1  2003      A   0.0   0.3   1.1
## 2  2003      B   1.1   0.4   0.6
## 3  2003      C  -0.1   0.3  -0.7
## 4  2004      A   1.0   0.2   0.7
## 5  2004      B  -0.1   1.6  -0.4
## 6  2004      C   0.1  -0.8   0.6
## 7  2005      A   7.0   0.7  -0.1
## 8  2005      B  -2.0   0.3  -1.4
## 9  2005      C  -4.0   0.0   2.5
```

If you want the row order the same as above, tack on `%>% arrange(areas, year)`. Note that you'll need at least dplyr 0.5.0.

---

#### Data

```
model2 <- structure(list(year = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 
    2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L), areas = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(-0.4, -1.7, 0.1, 0.4, -0.8, 
    -0.3, -3.8, 1.1, -1.7, 1.4, -0.4, 0.9), x2 = c(0.5, -0.7, -0.5, 
    -1, 1.6, -0.8, 0.2, 0, 0.6, 2, 0.7, -0.6), x3 = c(-0.5, -0.4, 
    0.5, -0.3, 0.3, -0.5, -0.6, 0, -1.7, 0.1, 1.4, -0.8)), .Names = c("year", 
    "areas", "x1", "x2", "x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```